# Apenas 2 casas após a virgula

Tags: c

Preciso que o resultado final mostre o numero inteiro e 2 casas após a virgula.

Tem como filtrar, digamos assim, isso para não mostrar todas as casas decimais?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    float r, resp; // declara variavel 

    printf("\n  Digite o valor do raio: "); // entrada do valor do raio
    scanf("%f",&r); // le entrada

    resp = pow (r,3); //calcula area 
    resp = resp * 3.14159; //calcula area
    resp = (resp * (4.0 / 3.0)); //calcula area

    printf("\n\n  VOLUME = %f\n\n  ",resp); //exibe resultado em tela

    return 0;
}
```

#### Exemplo

entro com valor 3, ele dá como saída `113.097237`, mas eu preciso que saia apenas `113.09`.

Comment: OUTRO PROBLEMA acredito que seja na declaracao de variaveis. Eu preciso entrar com o valor do raio de '1523' e como saida deve imprimir '14797486501.627' mas na verdade ele imprime '14797485056.000'. Alguma dica do que mudar ou qual variavel usar? ja pus long double e ele ficou com alguns resultados bem fora do normal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se precisas só de fazer o print e não fazer calculos com esse valor posteriormente podes:

```
printf("\n\n VOLUME = %.2f \n\n",  resp);
```

Comment: Obrigado Miguel !